# How to open a installed android app with button click inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I am new to android development and i need to know How to open quick office with a button click inside a fragment

any code examples??

any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to use the right intent... See more info here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can open **QuickOffice** from these lines of code

```
  Intent i = getActivity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.quickoffice.android");
            try {
                if (i != null) {
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    i = new Intent(app.getPackageName());
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) {
      }
```